# How do I make a proxy server I wrote work as an HTTPS server?

Tags: java, ssl-certificate

I have written a proxy server in Java and I need it to work as an HTTPS server which signs on its own certificate or uses a free CA.

What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Honestly I would just use apache in the frontend. The fact is that apache already act as a proxy, and that it add SSL on top on it.

this is exactly what I have made for my startup. We have a bunch of colaboratives tools online, protected with basic http authentication and SSL. this proved to be really effective and work well.

Or if you prefer and if you respect the servlet standard, then you can tell Tomcat for exemple to server page using SSL.

Anyway, my guess would be that you want to do it yourself and not just add a layer on your stack using an existing solution.

But if what interrest you is just the proxy mechanism and you don't care about how the content is encrypted you can be fine with this kind of solution.

Comment: actually i have to submit an exercise in which we have to write a proxy server and make it be https server as i mentioned above.
i will be grateful if you could  tell me what exactly should i do

Comment: Personnally I was to add SSL support on top of a protocol, I would use an API that provide SSL encryption and just integrate it into my stack. You can for exemple try to use the javax.net.ssl API (with a tutorial here : http://book.javanb.com/j2ee-security-for-Servlets-ejbs-and-web-services-applying-theory-and-standards/ch06lev1sec2.html). Another more didactic solution would be to implement SSLencryption yourself by studying the involved algorythms.

Comment: do you know maybe how can i make httpListener work with https by defining CA in the proxy?